# Trying to create a word count function

Tags: python, dictionary, packing

I'm trying to create a function:

```
word_count("I do not like it Sam I Am")
```

gets back a dictionary like:

```
{'i': 2, 'do': 1, 'it': 1, 'sam': 1, 'like': 1, 'not': 1, 'am': 1}
```

I've no idea how to begin.

Comment: What is your code so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def word_count(sentence):
  d = sentence.lower().split()
  d = {x: d.count(x) for x in d}
  return d
```

Comment: Can you please explain line 3. Thank you.

Comment: Oh nvm, got it. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas could work:

```
import pandas as pd
def word_count(string):
    df = pd.DataFrame(string.split())
    df['count'] = 1
    grouped = df.groupby(by=0).agg({'count':'count'}).reset_index()
    output = dict()
    for idx, row in grouped.iterrows():
        output[row[0]] = row['count']

    return output
```

Output:

> {'Am': 1, 'I': 2, 'Sam': 1, 'do': 1, 'it': 1, 'like': 1, 'not': 1}

Comment: Using pandas is like using a flamethrower to kill an ant

Comment: Yes indeed, I saw that readind your answer (!)

Comment: Atleast you got to practice pandas haha

Answer (score 0):

Use `collections.Counter`:

```
Counter(s.lower().split())
```

Output:

```
Counter({'am': 1, 'do': 1, 'i': 2, 'it': 1, 'like': 1, 'not': 1, 'sam': 1})
```